# Does P(A|B) = P(A) really imply independence?

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

I was going through KhanAcademy's practice questions and came across this question:

> 150 students in a tenth grade high school class take a survey about
> which video game consoles they own. 60 students answer that one of
> their consoles is a Playstation, 50 answer that one of their
> consoles is an Xbox. Out of these, there are 20 who have both
> systems.

> Let A be the event that a randomly selected student in the
> class has a Playstation and B be the event that the student has an
> XBOX.

> Is P(A|B) = P(A)? Are the events A and B independent?

Using the given values, P(A|B) = P(A) as P(A|B) = 20/50 = 2/5, and P(A) = 60/150 = 2/5, so they are equal.

Does this imply the events are independent though?

If I change the number of students that have Playstation to 50 (all else remaining the same), P(A|B) = 2/5 but P(A) = 1/3, they are not equal.

If these are truly independent events, shouldn't the original relationship hold up regardless of what the values are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistical independence implies that knowing the value of one will not give you any more information about the other. If you change one of the numbers and leave the rest the same, you're creating a different situation - now the proportion of students who own neither system is lower. If you know a student does not have an xbox, it would be more likely that they own neither. If you know they have an xbox, they are more likely to be one of the students who has a playstation (because there are fewer students with just a playstation).

That said, the dependence in this case is not strong. Variables are independent if $$P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$$
In this case that's $$\frac{20}{150} \ne (\frac{50}{150})^2$$

$$0.1333 \approx 0.1111 $$

which is pretty close.